# unable to append to cgroup v2 cgroup.subtree_controller

Tags: debian, cgroups

I have a tinker board 2s (like raspberry pi) running debian on kernel 4.4.194.

I enabled `cgroups v2` by adding `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` into the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file as supposed to.

the result of `ls /sys/fs/cgroup/` is:

`cgroup.controllers  cgroup.procs  cgroup.subtree_control  init.scope  system.slice  user.slice` which is correct it seems.

However, according to this [guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/using-cgroups-v2-to-control-distribution-of-cpu-time-for-applications_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel), now I need to add `cpu` and `chipset` into the `cgroup.subtree_control` as well, but this is where i am stuck.

```
echo '+cpu' >> /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
echo '+cpuset' >> /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
```

these results in permission denied errors... even when i sudo echo it, it results in the same thing.

`ls -l for /sys/fs/cgroup` shows:

```
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 06:52 cgroup.controllers
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 06:29 cgroup.procs
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 06:53 cgroup.subtree_control
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Dec  2 06:19 init.scope
drwxr-xr-x 53 root root 0 Dec  2 06:33 system.slice
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 0 Dec  2 06:19 user.slice
```

I'm at at loss as to who to add cpu and chipset into cgroup v2...

My purpose is to install kubernetes and connect the boards up as a cluster. but kubeadm failed saying that CPU and CPUSET is not found. That problem then led me to cgroups v2.

Comment: Regarding `sudo echo`, I think the problem you're experiencing is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853564/bash-echo-text-into-sudo-file Try those solutions out, or just `sudo -i` and then run the echo from the root shell.

Comment: @bgfvdu3w , I had the similar problem and I had changed the file permissions to solve it (sudo chmod o=rw <filename>) . But solution you linked worked without touching any permission(i.e. sudo bash -c ' echo "xxx" > [ file]  ' ). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although @bgfvdu3w stated the answer and the solution, one alternative is that: open up terminal window and simply write :

```
sudo -s<<START
echo '+cpu' >> /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
echo '+cpuset' >> /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
START
```

After writing an opening tag( first START word), terminal waits for new inputs for command will be performed under superuser's priviliges and puts ">" char at the beginin of terminal prompt line.  When you finished writing commands and enter after end tag (second START word)  terminal returns to normal prompt status and applies all commands between with superuser's priviliges.

When errors are due to permission while using sudo, I always use this option. If error continues, I will check permissions.